# python: get callback from linux

Tags: python, callback, listener, phantomjs

I have a script in phantomJS on Linux that renders a sample website:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.example.com', function () {
    page.render('test.pdf');
    console.log('pdf render finished')
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I am calling it from python with:

```
os.system('phantomjs test.js')
```

What I would like is a way for Python to know that the pdf render has finished; something like a listener for the line "pdf render finished", or something along those lines. How would a callback/listener like this be structured and how could it be implemented?

Comment: I think the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) gives you everything you need for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` only returns the processes return code. If you want to interact with the process, including reading it's STDOUT, use [popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). You can create a PIPE between your process and phantomjs and wait for 'pdf render finished'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the subprocess Module like this:

```
returncode =  subprocess.call(["phantomjs", "test.js"])

if returncode == 0:
   print "Application successfull executed"
else:
   print "There was an Error"
```

Comment: This is equivalent to his `os.system()` example. I believe he intends for the process to be long-running, and thus relying on the status code is not an option.